# How do I stay on the second form when the page is reloaded? Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to create an web-app that has only 2 pages. There are **two stages** of filling out forms on the first page. I can't create two separate pages. Two forms on one page.
So how do I stay on the second form when the page is reloaded?

Here is me component Register.vue:

```
    <form v-if="step === 1">
       <!-- some input fields about new user -->
    </form>
    <form v-if="step === 1">
       <!-- some input fields about additional info about new user -->
    </form>
```

What I tried:

```
data() {
  return {
     step: 1
  }
},
mounted() {
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
     if (this.step === 1) {
        this.step = 1;
     }
     if (this.step === 2) {
       this.step = 2;
     }
  }
```

},

Also tried to do the same in the created hook.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could set a cookie or use localstorage to set the last page visited.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep step inside the session storage so that the value will not be lost while reloading.

To set the value:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("step", step)
```

To retrieve the value:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("step")
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answer. But when I save step by sessionStorage, all the forms disappear. I can't understand why this is happening